# Java.security: 00 byte padded before a RSA signature recovery. Where does it come from?

Tags: java, security, rsa

I'm working on a project that needs to perform a digital signature on a plaintext. To do so, I perform a RSA decryption (with the private key) on the ciphertext. 
To verify the signature I compute the RSA encryption (using the Public Key) of the signature and compare it with the initial ciphertext.
If it's the same, the signature is valid. 
(this is basically a signaute with recovery).

I implemented this using Java.Security.
My problem: The recovered signature is exactly the same than the plaintext, except that a 0x00 byte is left-padded with it.
I absolutely need to remove this padding in the crypto calculation (I can't just take a sub-array of the recovered signature, and discard the first byte).

Here is my code:

**Main function:**

```
public class Test {

  /**
   * Method main
   *
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final String plaintext = "6A11541333FF10190123450101c101C8D4302FAE7D436A327276C9D2522AD8141FBF2B8B260FD94AB55E0C0C609A6EFB9D8391088066CA0A817F8E93D4918357C893B5753E32C71DC4FB27B16E2A008F84A928B3D649A5DB4AB7BD97464DACE8A8D4C9AB02B370F60DC703D5C893DC351FC8226E61C8EE0ED5EBAF64320530F662633152955BD1C25851CFF94E432CE89845625820836500062598AD669A6EB317DCF276E1A613C9C70CEA72A40B09C0F09B169D7DAC15A79AFCF154B52331BC";

    // Generate a RSA Key Pair
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen;
    try {
      keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
      final RSAKeyGenParameterSpec spec = new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(1544, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F0); // modulus length is 1544, the public exponent is 3
      keyGen.initialize(spec);

      final KeyPair pair = keyGen.genKeyPair();

      final String ciphertext = Utils.toString(Crypto.RSADecrypt(Utils.toBytes(plaintext), pair.getPrivate()));

      final String recovery = Utils.toString(Crypto.RSAEncrypt(Utils.toBytes(ciphertext), pair.getPublic()));

      System.out.println(recovery);

    }
    catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (final InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();

    }

  }

}
```

**Crypto functions:**

```
/**
   * Decrypt text using private key.
   *
   * @param text
   *          :encrypted text
   * @param key
   *          :The private key
   * @return plain text
   * @throws java.lang.Exception
   */
  public static byte[] RSADecrypt(final byte[] text, final PrivateKey key) {

    byte[] plainText = null;
    try {
      // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
      final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");

      // decrypt the text using the private key
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
      plainText = cipher.doFinal(text);

    }
    catch (final Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return plainText;
  }

  /**
   * Encrypt the plain text using public key.
   *
   * @param text
   *          : original plain text
   * @param key
   *          :The public key
   * @return Encrypted text
   * @throws java.lang.Exception
   */
  public static byte[] RSAEncrypt(final byte[] input, final PublicKey key) {

    byte[] cipherText = null;
    try {
      // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
      final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");

      // encrypt the plain text using the public key
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
      cipherText = cipher.doFinal(input);
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherText, 1, cipherText.length); // Ignore the first byte (sign byte)
    return cipherText;
  }
```

**Utils:**

```
/**
   * Corresponding String chain.
   *
   * @param bytes
   *          of bytes (example: apdu response)
   * @return Corresponding String chain.<br>
   *         Example: [(byte)0xEE, (byte)0xFF] -> "EEFF"
   */
  public static String toString(final byte[] bytes) {

    final char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];

    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {

      final int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
      hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
      hexChars[(j * 2) + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];

    }

    return new String(hexChars);

  }

  /** A field. */
  private static final char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
```

**Output:**

> 006A11541333FF10190123450101C101C8D4302FAE7D436A327276C9D2522AD8141FBF2B8B260FD94AB55E0C0C609A6EFB9D8391088066CA0A817F8E93D4918357C893B5753E32C71DC4FB27B16E2A008F84A928B3D649A5DB4AB7BD97464DACE8A8D4C9AB02B370F60DC703D5C893DC351FC8226E61C8EE0ED5EBAF64320530F662633152955BD1C25851CFF94E432CE89845625820836500062598AD669A6EB317DCF276E1A613C9C70CEA72A40B09C0F09B169D7DAC15A79AFCF154B52331BC

**Question:**
Where does the first (0x00) byte come from? How can I get it removed?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Chris

Comment: If you're signing and verifying something, why aren't you using the [Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html) class? It's made for exactly this case and handles everything correctly including the producing the hash of the content.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of steps required to properly perform RSA signing and RSA encryption. These steps include taking your raw data, formatting it, padding it, and converting it to a big integer to apply the RSA primitive operation. You may read the gory details of the PKCS#1 schemes in [RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447). These steps are tricky to get right, which is why for most people higher level classes should be used. As @Artjom B. has commented, for signing you should use the Signature class. If you don't use the signature class then you are responsible for all the steps yourself. In your particular case your data contains no padding or markers to indicate the beginning and end or your payload. There is no way for that information to be recovered on the other end, so you are left with a perplexing leading zero. It was, of course, there all along if you consider the data you provided as a big integer.